# Fullcalendar refetch events

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I need to re-fetch events for full calendar not only on calendar buttons, but on my own drop-down changes, because they define the criteria for events search. The only way I could pass values of dropdowns so far by using the `$.ajax`, but now the events don't get to the calendar. I'm missing something, as I don't fully seem to understand the functionality.

```
$(function () {
    InitializeCalendar();

    $("#ProjectId").change(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    });

    $("#JobId").change(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    });

    $("#StoreId").change(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    });

    $("#OrderType").change(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    });

    $("#ShippingId").change(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    });
});

function InitializeCalendar() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: function (start, end) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Calendar/GetEvents/',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),
                    projectId: $("#ProjectId option:selected").val(),
                    storeId: $("#StoreId option:selected").val(),
                    jobId: $("#JobId option:selected").val(),
                    orderType: $("#OrderType option:selected").val(),
                    shippingId: $("#ShippingId option:selected").val()
                }

                **SOMETHING MISSING HERE** 

                //this puts calendar into infinite loop
                //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(double start, double end, int? projectId, int? storeId, string orderType, int? shippingId, int? jobId)
{
    // Some code...

    IList<OrderEvent> events = orderDTOs.Select(orderDTO => new OrderEvent {
        id = orderDTO.OrderId,
        title = orderDTO.OrderId.ToString(), 
        start = ToUnixTimespan(orderDTO.CreatedDate), 
        end = ToUnixTimespan(orderDTO.CreatedDate.AddHours(1)), 
        url = "/Order/Search"
    }).ToList();

    return Json(events, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to know how this was solved! Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this? The answer does not work..

Answer (score 4):

In the interests of future readers, here is the correct solution for FullCalendar v2.

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Calendar/GetEvents/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
            end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),
            projectId: $("#ProjectId option:selected").val(),
            storeId: $("#StoreId option:selected").val(),
            jobId: $("#JobId option:selected").val(),
            orderType: $("#OrderType option:selected").val(),
            shippingId: $("#ShippingId option:selected").val()
        }
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should put the `refetchEvents` call in the events ajax call. The `refetchEvents` will call that ajax again - thus the infinite loop.

Also, I think the way you are sending data to the calendar from your drop-downs is fine. Try with removing the `refetchEvents` call from the ajax call and see if it works.

And you can use the success callback of the ajax call to process the returned events from your controller - if you need to.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this should work for you. Just have full calendar refetch the events through the success function of your ajax call, therefore it should only refetch after each call and not infinitely like it currently does:

```
events: function (start, end) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Calendar/GetEvents/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
            end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),
            projectId: $("#ProjectId option:selected").val(),
            storeId: $("#StoreId option:selected").val(),
            jobId: $("#JobId option:selected").val(),
            orderType: $("#OrderType option:selected").val(),
            shippingId: $("#ShippingId option:selected").val()
        }

       **SOMETHING MISSING HERE**
       success: function(data) {
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
            console.log('successfully refetched events');
       }

       //this puts calendar into infinite loop
       //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    });
```